# Send array of objects as POST data without ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, input

I have an HTML form. When the form is submitted, a jQuery code is executed to append an array of objects before data is sent to the server. Each object contains information retrieved outside the form.

```
<form method="post" id="formID" action="test.php" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <!-- form inputs -->
</form>
```

```js
$('#formID').submit(function() {
    var form = $(this);     
    $('.file').each(function(index) {
        var filedata = {
            name: $(this).find('.name').text(), 
            ordernum: index, 
            size: $(this).find('.size').text()
        };
        form.append('<input type="hidden" name="filedata[]" value="' + filedata + '"/>');
    });
});
```

My goal would be to retrieve these information on server side. Unfortunately, when I output `$_POST` data, I only get a generic `Object` data.

```php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST['filedata']);
echo '</pre>';

/* output */
Array
(
    [0] => [object Object]
    [1] => [object Object]
)
```

Is there a way to send an array of objects when submitting a form to server without using AJAX requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stringify the object you concatenate to the HTML:

```
form.append('<input type="hidden" name="filedata[]" value="' + JSON.stringify(filedata) + '"/>');
```

You then need to deserialize that value in your PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['filedata'] as $d => $data)
{
    $obj = json_decode($data);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($obj['name']);
    print_r($obj['ordernum']);
    print_r($obj['size']);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I get the following error on server side: `Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\xampp\htdocs\upload\controller\testController.php on line 22`.

Comment: You need to loop through each value in the `$_POST['filedata']` array. I updated my answer for you

Comment: Unfortunately, still doesn't work (I get a blank output). Maybe there's something wrong in `$_POST['filedata']`? When I output it I get `Array
(
    [0] => {
    [1] => {
)`

Comment: The would be an issue, yes. What do you see in the console if you do the following in the JS `console.log(JSON.stringify(filedata))`?

Comment: This seems to be correct: `{"name":"privacy.jpg","ordernum":0,"size":"197,07 kB"}`, `{"name":"copyright.jpg","ordernum":1,"size":"108,83 kB"}`

Comment: Find it out. The inverted commas into stringified data was in conflict with those in append command. I've changed it to `form.append("<input type='hidden' name='filedata[]' value='" + JSON.stringify(filedata) + "'/>");`.  And then to access members correctly also changed this on PHP: `$obj = (array) json_decode($data);`. Maybe consider to update the answer to fix those issues. Thanks for your help.